# Instantiating a class in VB

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class

I'm needing help with a little instatiating problem...

This is the code i'm using for the ATM:

```
   Dim ID As String
    Dim _PinPad As PinPad
    Dim _CashDespenser As CashDespenser
    Dim _PrintManager As PrintManager
    Dim _CardReader As CardReader
    Public Sub New(ByVal _PinPad As PinPad, ByVal _CashDespenser As CashDespenser, ByVal _PrintManager As PrintManager, ByVal _CardReader As CardReader)
        MyBase.New()
        Me._PinPad = _PinPad
        Me._CardReader = _CardReader
        Me._CashDespenser = _CashDespenser
        Me._PrintManager = _PrintManager
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal ID As String, ByVal _PinPad As PinPad, ByVal _CashDespenser As CashDespenser, ByVal _PrintManager As PrintManager, ByVal _CardReader As CardReader)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.ID = ID
        Me._PinPad = _PinPad
        Me._CardReader = _CardReader
        Me._CashDespenser = _CashDespenser
        Me._PrintManager = _PrintManager
    End Sub
```

And Now I'm Trying to get it to instatiate in the Form's load event which looks like this:

```
Dim ThisATM As New ATM
        Dim ThisKeyCard As New KeyCard("1234", "5678", "Mikki Monster")

        ThisATM.getCashDespenser.Dispensecash()
        ThisATM.getID()
        ThisATM.getPinPad.checkpin()
        ThisATM.getPrintManager.print("Pikachu Rules")
```

The KeyCard class worked fine but the ATM class will not work at all. It seems to not be able to let me put in the parameters after the "New ATM" bit... What do you suggest?
[Link For an Image of the parameters](http://i40.tinypic.com/29qmvth.jpg)

Comment: When you say "the ATM class will not work at all," do you mean the Intellisense does not popup when entering `New ATM`?  Have you imported all the necessary namespaces?  Is your code for class `ATM` currently able to compile without errors?

Comment: Intellisense does pop up when typing out the parameters its says (_PinCard as AssementATM.Pincard,_CashDespenser As AssementATM.CashDespenser, _PrintManager As AssementATM.PrintManager,_CardReader As AssementATM.CardReader) And it does not compile, it has a few errors just to do with what i have basically mentioned.

Comment: Do you get a specific error message that you can post?

Comment: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
Public Sub New()
   MyBase.New()
End Sub
```

to your ATM class. Then you need to change your

`MyBase.New()`

statments in the other constructors to

```
Me.New()
```